# Absolute positioned element in relative parent does not overlap other elements

Tags: css, css-position, z-index

I have a list (ul - li) where the li's float so I have a grid with blocks.
Every li has position relative.

Inside every li I have a div (with class 'more') that is hidden and only showed if you hover a it's parent li. The .more div I want to attach STARTING at the bottom of the li going down and OVERLAPPING any other li's without pushing this other li's away/down.
Because it's attached to the bottom I set the bottom position of the .more div to a negative value matching the exact height of the more div.

This more or less works but the .more div is always shown UNDER the other li's. It's only overlapping it's parent.

I tried already to give all the li's a static z-index of 5 and all the .more div's a static z-index of 500, but this still doesn't help.

A made a jsFiddle of it all: http://jsfiddle.net/yNS6R/

Relevant code:

```
    ul li
    {
        background: yellow;
        border: 1px solid green;
        float: left;
        height: 200px;
        margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
        position: relative;
        width: 22%;
        z-index: 2;
    }

    ul li .more
    {
        background: red;
        border-bottom: 1px solid green;
        border-left: 1px solid green;
        border-right: 1px solid green;
        bottom: -50px;
        display: none;
        height: 50px;
        left: -1px;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 500;
    }

    ul li:hover .more
    {
        display: block;
    }
```

Comment: Try to remove the z-index property from "ul li" elements in your CSS

Answer (score 1):

Remove `z-index` out of your `ul li` and `ul li .more`, and add it to `:hover` state:

```
ul li:hover .more {             
   display: block;
   z-index: 1;
}
```

[Updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yNS6R/1/)

Answer (score 0):

this is only because of you add z-index to li. If you remove z-index of li then it will work fine.

```
ul li
{
    background: yellow;
    border: 1px solid green;
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 22%;
    z-index: 2; // here you add z-index to li
}
```